# How to implement validation error messages in django rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am just starting to learn python and django rest framework. I am creating the sample apis in django. I am having a problem where i need to set the validation error messages.

For example **email is requied or email already exists**

Here is my code:

Serializer Class:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        #fields = ['id','title','author','date']
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
def post(self,request):
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.error,status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)


    def _str_(self):
        #self.fields['email'].required = False
        return self.title
```

Error is:

```
'ArticleSerializer' object has no attribute 'error'
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to handle the validation manually:

```py
def post(self, request):
    serializer = ArticleSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

This will raise an Exception, but the exception will be handled by DRF (as long as you're using it correctly) and will return a 400 status code with the error messages as expected.

Also, this view does more or less exactly the same as a [CreateAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview), you'd probably be better off using that than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `serializer.errors` (plural) instead of `serializer.error`.

That will avoid the error you're getting and it will return the HTTP error you're expecting.